# In Haskell, can syncing hardware clock while retrieving the time cause a serious problem?

Tags: linux, haskell, operating-system

Let’s say I have this:

```
main = do
        void (forkIO (forever $ (threadDelay 10000) >> callCommand "hwclock --systohc"))
        let loop = do 
                     mytime <- getCurrentTime
                     if (mytime > (fromJust(parseISO8601 “2021-12-10T13:10:09+0000”))) then (print “hello”) else ((threadDelay 100) >> loop)
        loop
```

Is there any serious issue that can happen here relating to the time potentially being synced at the same time as when I request the time with getCurrentTime?

Comment: I'd guess any modern OS should guarantee that setting and getting the time is an atomic operation. You should read either the time value before it's set, or the one right after. Other than that, what serious issues are you thinking of?

Comment: This is a question about the OS rather than Haskell. I'm inclined to say that it is off-topic here, or at least should have the right tags.

Comment: @chi I was thinking maybe causing my program to crash, but really seeing if anyone here recognized any possible negative outcome was something I wanted check to be safe

Comment: @PaulJohnson I added the operating-system tag

Comment: On linux you can even concurrently read and write form the same file, without any serious issue. IIRC, atomicity on file read/writes is only guaranteed in a weak way, but it does not matter here. I'd be very surprised if reading/writing a few bytes for the clock were not atomic, since by comparison it's a much simpler problem than handling files.

Comment: If the hardware clock is so unreliable that you need to sync it every 10 seconds, I would consider just resyncing prior to every call to `getCurrentTime` rather than periodically, or having a separate service handle updating it. There's also the issue of polling the system time every 100ms rather than using an alarm signal.

Comment: @chepner `threadDelay` expects microseconds, so it's much worse than that. Still, I hope the code above is just a MCVE to explain the issue, not actual "production" code.

Comment: @chepner yes that was just an example; I do it more like every 20 minutes since the OS clock updates from the NTP server every 11 minutes

Comment: @chi Thank you for your comments. I have read some more into this based on what you’ve said, and now I feel safe running the analogous code to what I posted here in my program. Good news is that it hasn’t crashed yet hahah